# Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1

Tags: version-12

I am considering whether to download the new version, is all this effort worthwhile, so I would like to know what is the most important difference between versions 12.0 and 12.1?

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) but I think this question is much too broad, and not a good fit for a QA site.

Comment: Yep, depends what you care about. Not much effort to download and have a play.

Answer (score 4):

Summary of New Features in 12.1
A list of key new features since 12.0, including features experimental in 12.1.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn121.html

Comment: Thanks to Szabolcs